# Formatting returned values from a function

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have this function containing two lists. One of them has a bunch of strings within it, but the other is filled with integers generated from random numbers. When it is done, I have a for statement that prints out the information in the format I desire. But that's the problem, I can format the information within the function itself. But I need to pass the data over to another function and display it in the same manner

```
def charAbility():
    pAbility = ['Str', 'Dex', 'Con', 'Int', 'Wis', 'Cha']
    pScore = []
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        randomNumber = random.randint(7, 18)
        pScore.append(randomNumber)
        i = i + 1
return pAbility, pScore
```

To get what I want printed within the function, I have this piece of code:

```
for score, ability in zip(pAbility, pScore):
    print str(score) + ":\t\t " + str(ability)
```

Is there a way I can take the returned values and print it in the same fashion in another function?

Comment: What do you want, You want two lists as return value and print them in another function ?

Comment: So what's wrong with returning the formatted result in function? `return (str(score) + ":\t\t " + str(ability))`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are simply looking for this:

```
param1, param2 = charAbility()
```

## Explanation

Your method is returning two values `pAbility, pScore`. If you are to do this simply:

```
param = charAbility()
```

You will still have access to both of your returns, however, they are returned as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

Simplified example of what is happening:

```
def charAbility():
    return 1, 2
param = charAbility()
print(param)
(1, 2)
```

So, to handle the return in to their own variables, so you can pass it to a new method, you should be using the example I provided above. To re-iterate:

```
param1, param2 = charAbility()
```

Now you can pass `param1` (which will hold `pAbility`) and `param2` (which will be holding `pScore`) to whatever other method you need to send it to:

```
some_other_method(param1, param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :-

```
def charAbility():
    pAbility = ['Str', 'Dex', 'Con', 'Int', 'Wis', 'Cha']
    pScore = []
    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        randomNumber = random.randint(7, 18)
        pScore.append(randomNumber)
        i = i + 1
    return pAbility, pScore

def otherFunc():
    score, ability = charAbility()

    for iscore, strability in zip(ability, pScore):
        print str(iscore) + ":\t\t " + str(strability)

otherFunc() # function in module scope
```

Comment: This is not quite right. You are mixing up `score, ability` and `pAbility` inside the `otherFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

You should call your existing function and assign the two lists to two different variables, or together they will be returned as a tuple. Then it would be cleanest to use string formatting to print the results:

```
scorelist, abilitylist = charAbility()

for score,ability in zip(scorelist,abilitylist):
    print "{}:\t\t{}".format(score,ability)
```

Alternatively, with one variable:

```
combinedlists = charAbility()

for pair in zip(*combinedlists):
    print "%s:\t\t%s" % pair
```